# Jquery animation on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I'm very new to jQuery and I've been trying to achieve something like this http://jsfiddle.net/rniestroj/nZhbg/

but it doesn't seem to be working on my code. I don't understand if I have the jQuery part wrong?

Here is what I have:

In the code, the second part of the jQuery with img0...etc is the fade in and out of my header.

index.php

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>

    <!-- JQuery script for fade in and fade out of the whole page-->

 <script>
 $(".circle1").hover(
     function(){
        $(".circle1info").animate({left: '+=1000',bottom: '+=1000'}, 1750); 
     }, 
     function(){
        $(".circle1info").animate({left: '-=1000',bottom: '-=1000'}, 750);  
     });

 $( "#img0" ).delay(1000).fadeIn(3000, function() {
   $( "#img1" ).fadeIn(3000, function() {
     $( "#img2" ).fadeIn(3000, function() {
        $( "#img3" ).fadeIn(3000, function() {
            $( "#img4" ).fadeIn(3000, function() {
                $( "#rightpanel" ).fadeIn(500, function() {
                     $( "#leftpanel" ).fadeIn(500, function() {
                    });             
                });             
            });
        });
     });
  });
  return false;
});
</script>

<img class="smdmascot" src="/images/fade/samplemd_mascot.png"><br>
<img class="circle4" src="/images/fade/circle4.png"><br>
<img class="circle3" src="/images/fade/circle3.png"><br>
<img class="circle2" src="/images/fade/circle2.png"><br>
<img class="circle1" src="/images/fade/circle1.png"><br>
<img class="circle1info" src="/images/fade/coupon_slider.png">


 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS: (I took some of the img0...etc stuff out so its easier to look at)

> ```
>   a:link { color: #FFFFFF; } 
>   a:visited { color: #FFFFFF; } 
>   a:hover { color: #000000; } 
>   a:active { color: #FFFFFF; }
>
>
>   .maindiv {
>   position: absolute;
>
>   }
>   .circle1 {
>       position: absolute;
>       z-index: 5;
>       left: 545px;
>       top: 715px;
>
>       }
>       .circle1info {
>       position: absolute;
>       z-index: -5;
>       left: 545px;
>       top: 715px;
>
>
>       }
>   .circle2 {
>       position: absolute;
>       z-index: 4;
>       left: 579px;
>     top: 600px;
>
>       }
>   .circle3 {
>       position: absolute;
>       z-index: 3;
>       left: 597px;
>       top: 515px;
>
>       }
>   .circle4 {
>       position: absolute;
>       z-index: 2;
>       left: 618px;
>     top: 450px;
>
>       }
>   .smdmascot {
>       position: absolute;
>       z-index: 1;
>       left: 580px;
>     top: 320px;
>
>       }
>
> </style>
> ```

I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Queueing actions in the manner you have is not good code. Have a look in the API for callback functions, as well as loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$( "#img0" ) is selecting any element whose id is img0, and I don't see any in your code!

Comment: OP states: `i took some of the img0...etc stuff out so its easier to look at`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He said that in the CSS part. Anyway, he should have taken off the scripts related to those elements otherwise it's confusing!

Comment: actually its not that i just figure it out. So apparently for jquery you must have the script BELOW the images your applying your animation to. lol! I just facepalmed so hard. Thank you for the reply though!

Comment: @Taz or you can run your code once the DOM is loaded and you wouldn't depend on the position of your script.

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: oh cool! I'll try that! Thank you! I've only been introduced to jquery a week ago so i'm still very new at this and trying understand it. Thanks for your help! =)